# Get interaction.reply() latency

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I know there already were a lot of questions about how to make a `ping` command for your discord.js bot, but my question is kinda different because I want to make this command for `interaction` and not `message`. I tried using

```js
Date.now() - interaction.createdTimestamp
```

to get interaction ping but as result I get: `-1007ms`. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Not sure if [CommandInteraction#createdAt](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/CommandInteraction?scrollTo=createdAt) will make any difference but worth a shot

Comment: @Elitezen actually there is a difference, it says `-224ms` now

Comment: @Elitezen the only problem is that my bot shows ping as negative value, the ping itself is correct, should I search for solution or just replace `-` with ` `?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Math.abs()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs) to get the absolute value of a number

```js
const delay = Math.abs(Date.now() - interaction.createdTimestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just reverse it

```
interaction.createdTimestamp - Date.now()
```